# Calculate the standard error of the difference between two independent proportions

Tags: r, statistics

Edit: This may be better for stats stack exchange but I'm in a data mining class and we use R so I'll ask it here as well just in case anyone knows how to do this with R instead of manually.

**Here's the question:** A survey of 500 males and 700 females showed that 132 males and 226 females agreed with a particular statement. Use this information to calculate the proportions of males and females that agreed with the statement. This will give you the values for p1 and p2. Use this to calculate q1 and q2. Now calculate the standard error of the difference between two independent proportions. Then determine the confidence interval for the difference between two independent proportions for the 95 confidence level.

I think my formulas are wrong because they're not the standard error of the *difference* between two independent proportions or the confidence interval for the *difference* between two independent proportions like what these charts show, I have the specific bottom equation zoomed in. I'm still unsure what the q1 and q2 refers to.

[image]

[image]

Here's what I have for formulas so far:

```
p1 = 0.264 (132/500)
p2 = 0.322857 (226/700)
q1 = 
q2 =

Stdev1 = sqrt (p(1-p)) = (1-0.264)*0.264 = sqrt(0.194304) = 0.44079927404
Stdev2 = sqrt(p(1-p)) = (1-0.322857)*0.322857 = sqrt(0.218620357) = 0.4675685586

Std error = standard deviation / square root(number of samples)
Std error1 = 0.44079927404/sqrt(500) = 0.44079927404/22.360679775 = 0.019713142
Std error2 = 0.4675685586/sqrt(700) = 0.4675685586/26.4575131106 = 0.017672430

Standard deviation = in R it’s sd() and in sd you need series of values, 
    m = mean of values
    x – m = difference of values minus mean
    sum of squared diff from the mean = sum(x-m)^2
    square root [(sum of squared diff from the mean) / (sample size -1)]

Confidence interval (95%)  = 
 
    Margin of error = Square root [p(1-p)/n]  * 1.96  //n = sample size, 1.96 is 95% confidence interval
    Margin error1 = sqrt(0.194304/500)   * 1.96  = 0.01971314282  * 1.96 = 0.038637759 
    Margin error2 = sqrt(0.218620357/700) ] * 1.96 = 0.01767240787  * 1.96 = 0.034637919 
    
    P + margin of error = Upper confidence interval
        p1 = 0.264+0.038637759 = 0.302637759
        p2 = 0.322857 + 0.034637919 = 0.35749419
    P – margin of error = Lower confidence interval
        p1 = 0.264-0.038637759 = 0.225362241
        p2 = 0.322857 - 0.034637919 = 0.288219081

    P1 CI =  0.225362241 <  0.264 < 0.302637759
    P2 CI =  0.288219081 < 0.322857 < 0.35749419
```

Comment: Why don't you discuss this with your lecturer instead? He or she will most likely be happy  to help and glad that you are trying.

Comment: Most professors don't respond unless you're in person so it can't be an online class like this one, I'm one in hundreds of students, but I do have one extremely rude professor who will fight me and I'll just keep raising my hand and asking the same question over and over until the class has been very disrupted and it gets heated.  The best I can do is leave a bad review but that doesn't do much. @Valentas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unaware that Cross Validated, the stats focused stack exchange was the more appropriate place for this question, [here is the question with the solution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547772/calculate-the-standard-error-of-the-difference-between-two-independent-proportio) to this question.